# Reading and writing vector<bool> to a file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I am having a vector whose size can be really big (1 million elements). I am wrote the contents of the vector to a file as byte values. I am not able to figure out how I can read the byte values back into the vector.

Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // Filling a vector with values
  std::vector<bool> ve;
  ve.push_back(true);
  ve.push_back(false);
  ve.push_back(true);
  ve.push_back(false);
  ve.push_back(true);
  // Printing the values of the vector
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ve.size(); i++)
      cout << ve.at(i) << ".";
  cout << endl;

  // Writing the vector contents to a file
  const char* file_name = "abc.txt";
  ofstream outfile(file_name, ios::out | ios::binary);
  outfile.write((const char*)&(ve[0]), ve.size());
  outfile.close();
  // Reading the file and filling the vector with values
  ifstream infile ("abc.txt", ifstream::binary);
  vector<bool> out_ve((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  while( !infile.eof() )
      out_ve.push_back(infile.get());

  // Checking if the values read are the same as the original values
  cout << "SIZE: " << out_ve.size() << endl;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < out_ve.size(); i++)
    cout << out_ve.at(i) << ".";
  cout << endl;

  infile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

[edit] Closed the file after writing and the output is very different from the input.

```
1.0.1.0.1.
SIZE: 6
1.1.1.0.1.1.
```

How can I get the correct elements into the vector out_ve?

Comment: I can't even compile that... You're taking the address of a temporary here "outfile.write((const char*)&(ve[0]), ve.size());", since `ve[0]` returns a reference wrapper for the corresponding bool in the vector.

Comment: I got a warning, "Taking address of temporary" which I ignored. I followed this methods for writing the entire file contents to the buffer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693089/fastest-way-to-write-large-stl-vector-to-file-using-stl

Comment: Does one need to close the file before you can read it back?

Comment: You should usually take warnings as compiler errors. In this case, it is an error, since you are taking the address of a temporary and then writing the contents of that address into a file. That sir, is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm deleting the "AND" question because going to be complicated keeping track of the answers to two separate questions here. Please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @mfontanini: why is it undefined behavior to write the raw bytes of a temporary out to a file?

Comment: @KenBloom You're right ;). Fair enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing data from most STL containers cannot be done with `outfile.write((const char*)&(ve[0]), ve.size());` because they manage their memory in complex ways that's fundamental to the way they operate. With `vector`, it works, because memory storage is contiguous, but `vector<bool>` is special because of the way it packs multiple bools into a single byte. As commenters have already pointed out, `ve[0]` returns a special temporary quasi-reference type, and writing that reference out by casting to a `char*` will produce something totally unrelated to the data that's in the vector.

Even if this construction gave you access to the raw memory of the vector, the code that you're using to write out the data is incompatible with the code that you're using to read in the data. The code that you're using to write out the data *would* pack 8 `bool` entries into each `char`, but the code you're using to read in the data converts each `char` into a single `bool`.

Since you're reading back your data using an `istreambuf_iterator`, why not write it out the same way:

```
std::copy(ve.begin(), ve.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile));
```

This writes out one `bool` per byte.

If you want to write out data in a packed representation that writes one bit per `bool`, I think you'll need to invent your own input and output iterators.

Comment: thanks for clearing it out. But why am i getting an extra value after performing the write using std::copy(ve.begin(), ve.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(outfile)); ? i.e. I get the size of 'out_ve' as 6 and and extra value gets printed.

Comment: @SyncMaster: you need to get rid of the   `while(!infile.eof()) out_ve.push_back(infile.get());` I lack a good explanation for why the  body of that loop executes, though.

Comment: thanks. but if this vector is really big (100 million in my case) it takes considerable time in writing all the values to the file as it has to iterate through the vector. Is there a better way to write the vector contents?

Comment: @Syncmaster: I can't think of anything obvious off the top of my head. (That doesn't mean there isn't one, but you'll have to be clever, and you'll have to know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 1):

`vector<bool>` is not a real `vector`.  Code you found elsewhere to work on vectors, won't.  And you must not ignore the "address of a temporary".  This line

```
outfile.write((const char*)&(ve[0]), ve.size());
```

will not work on `vector<bool>`.

The issue is that the thing you're taking the address of isn't the type you think it is.

Answer (score -2):

try this for the AND opperation:

```
#define logical_and(x, y)   ((x==y) ? x | y)
```

you should look into operator overloading and make an operator that returns the next unsigned char within the file then use atoi to convert the value to an integer

Ex.

```
template<typename T>
  T operator << (ifstream& file)
  {
    return reinterpret_cast<T>(file.get());
  };
```

the above is just an example (not tested. haven't use c++ templates in a while so it may need reworking

best of luck,

Alexander Frankland (Tandex)

Comment: That "AND" operation is all messed up.

Comment: -1: This answer is just plain wrong -- it won't even compile, and it's now offtopic since I edited this question to only ask one question.